# L2 Circuit ober BGP Signaled MPLS

Tags: cisco, mpls

We are providing MPLS Network services to Customers via Ethernet Links. Our CPEs (mainly Cisco) are linked via VLAN Subinterfaces to the PEs (Juniper MX). Due to the increasing demand of Multiple Services (Internet, VPN, Cloud, etc.) im thinking of extending the MPLS Domain from the PEs to the CPEs, singaled via labeled BGP.

Pros:

- just one single Layer2 underlay Link necessary, Service Virtualisation is based on MPLS Labels, so lower configuration impact.
- Moving Configuration Complexity away from PE toi CPE

Cons until now:

- additional Licenses necessary on Cisco Side (AX, or Network Avantage)
- no IP ACSs possible on the WAN Link
- Qos has to be done on MPLS-QoS bits so IP-DSCP Values have to be translated to MPLS-QoS

Now i wonder... is it possible to implement Layer2 Services in such a setup?
AFAIK Cisco is not supporting BGP Signaled circuits (Kompella). Even in VPLS Setup BGP is only used for Discovery purposes.

But, in my understanding of Martini (LDP Signaled Circuits),it should still be possible in the above mentioned Setup.
In Martini's draft a direct LDP Session is established between the two tunnel endpoints only to exchange tunnel information, not to exchange Path information.

Has anyone implemented such a setup and can confirm that this should be possible? Is the configuration straight forward like within a plain LDP domain or are there some specials to mention?
Are there any cons i havn't thought of?

Comment: Have you considered QinQ?